# How do I change a website video to m3U8 format?

Tags: m3u8

Can anyone walk me through the steps of taking a video from our website and changing it to a m3U8 so we can then insert it to our app dashboard to have video on our app?

Comment: what format is the video currently - mp4?

Comment: http://samalpramod.blogspot.ie/2013/03/how-convert-mp4-file-to-http-live.html

Answer (score 2):

Download [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)

then download a http segmenter e.g. [apple's one](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) or the [google one](https://code.google.com/p/httpsegmenter/downloads/detail?name=segmenter-r6.7z)

Now run the command prompt using cmd.
Go to bin directory of the FFMPEG from the command prompt. 
Type `ffmpeg –h` to find various option of the ffmpeg.

This sample code converts a mp4 to a ts file:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4  -acodec libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 320x320 -vcodec libx264 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts myvideo.ts
```

then run the segmenter to break up the ts file into smaller segments

```
 segmenter -i myvideo.ts -d 20 -o la -x test/myvideo.m3u8
```

add the following to your htaccess file if you are running on apache

```
    .M3U8   application/x-mpegURL
    .ts   video/MP2T
```

that's about it

Answer (score 0):

Use gstreamill, which can transcode video to m3u8 format.

Comment: Can you add a code sample to better elaborate how to implement gstreamill?